# what do you want to test coverage on when using pytest

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a python project with tests written in `tests/`

If I run `python -m pytest --cov tests/` that seems to give me code coverage for all files in tests/. If I run `python -m pytest --cov=. tests/` that seems to give me coverage results for all files in the project.

When we want code coverage, are we asking for coverage in terms of what the tests cover (so my first CLI should be the one to run) or should results be based on src/ files?

Comment: Point to src directory: `python -m pytest --cov=src tests/`. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer if I point to source, my coverage results show less than 95% for files in src/ but 99-100% for files in tests/. Should i be looking at results from tests/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are missing the [flag `term-missing`](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reporting.html#reporting), that's what I am using and there is no coverage for `./tests` shown:

```
set PYTHONPATH=<fullpath_to>src
pytest --self-contained-html -s --durations=0 --cov-report html:cov_html --cov-report term-missing --cov=src tests/unittests -vv
```

Comment: Okay that worked! Thank you. So how do I interpret the results? Is it that anything under "missing" has no test coverage?

Comment: Yes, 'missing' means, that code was not tested.